# static global structure variable value changes to FF

Tags: c, embedded, keil

I have a `static global structure` variable say `Struct1` in a file which is modified only in the file(say Struct1file.c)

I have a `State Machine` in the same file(Struct1file.c) which is called within a task(Struct1Task) after every **1ms**. This `State Machine` has functions which access and changes the value of the `static global structure` variable. After certain number of times, the statemachine is called, all the variables within the global structure variable changes to **0xFF** except the arrays within `Strcut1`.

```
typedef Struct1{
short int Data[20];
char      cData[40];
bool     flag1;
short int value1;
bool flag2;
short int value2;
estate switch_var;
Callback callbackfunction();
};
```

All the values within `Struct1` change except the values in `Data` and `Data1`.

**Minimal code:**

```
switch(Strcut1var.switch_var)
{
  case IDLE: ReadintoData();
             Strcut1var.switch_var = TAKE_ACTION;
  break;
  case TAKE_ACTION: if(Struct1var.Data[1]== some_enum)
                    {
                     Callbackfunction(Data,LengthofData);
                     Struct1var.switch_var = SEND;
                    }
  break;
  case SEND: if(Struct1var.flag1 == TRUE)
                 SendData();
  break;
  }
```

I am working on **C and on Keil**. I tried changing the stack and heap size, but to no effect!

Comment: youll have to post the code, anything can happen to that `Struct1`. run gdb over the app, and put a watch on any of these fields which are getting set..

Comment: Can you post some Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?

Comment: Can you put some code to show how you are working out with structure ?

Comment: posted the minimal code

Comment: @amdixon I am observing the the structure variable on a watch window. It doesn't change after it enters the call back function as well. But just after a certain number of times after entering the state machine. And there are no other tasks running in parallel

Comment: in terms of the minimal code, it should be contained in a complete driver program which replicates this exact issue. for debugging, you should still be able to see the statements/lines where the fields are set, maybe make your minimal driver program a loop over the call back and see what gdb watch tells you

Comment: @amdixon I cannot see the lines where the structure variable  is set to FF because it happens during the delay and before entering the State machine after a certain time.

Comment: ok, then post a complete minimal example, should contain the minimal code to reproduce the issue ( ie. we have no visibility of Callbackfunction, SendData, etc. ). this complete code should be self-contained and have a main function

Comment: @Prash: check your ISR routine. Are you modifying something there ?

Comment: @amidxon SendData sends the data over SPI and Call back function just gets the data from an other higher layer.

Comment: @Amol checked already.. nothing! I am going to do a hardware debugging now and will tell you people if I find out the issue!

Comment: Since FF is usually the default value of an unprogrammed memory cell, it seems that stack overflow could be a likely cause of the bug. Does the stack on your particular MCU grow towards such an area of memory? Check the stack pointer in your debugger when you encounter this bug. Also `Callback callbackfunction();` seems very fishy, this is most likely an incorrect declaration. You don't declare function pointers in that way no matter how you have typedef:ed them.

Comment: typedef void (*Callback)(char* Data,short int Length);

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED ! Thanks to the feature of hardware breakpoints in ARM Cortex. I was able to track which function was writing the particular memory location i.e. the address of Struct1var. @Amol you were right. Since I was using SPI , the ISR of SPI was activated every time as there was reception of FF on SPI. And I had sent the address of Struct1var.Data in ReadIntoData(). So, each time FF was received, it triggered the ISR which had access to Struct1var.Data. The ISR incremented the address of Struct1var.Data and saved FF. So, Structvar1Data was not changed but the other variables!

Comment: @Prash : Good to see that its working !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the values within Struct1 change except the values in Data and Data1.

In which case the most likely cause is overrunning the bounds of `Data1`.

> I am working on C and on Keil.

Keil provide compilers for several targets.  It would be more useful to know the target, and the debug capability available to you. If hardware memory access breakpoints are available for example, you could place a write access breakpoint on the address of the `flag1` member, and determine precisely where it is overwritten.

You could probably avoid the problem [by not using global data](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals) in the first instance.  Even if the problem is not avoided by that it is certainly easier to debug because use of access functions provide an opportunity to use more generally available program-counter breakpoints to trap data access.